# Getting an error while running "nodemon app" comannd

Tags: node.js, nodemon

i've downloaded express package and nodemon, I created a server and rendered all of my ejs files .  while running "nodemon app" command I'm getting this error, what specifically the problem is? :

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\my port> nodemon app
[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1316:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1364:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1450:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Users\user\Desktop\my port\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\my port\app.js:16:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1343:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: The port 3000 is already being used by something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system has something already running on port 3000.

you can do either of 2,

1. Kill process running on 3000
2. Or Use different port in your current app (like 3001, 5000, etc)

Answer (score 0):

hi use this and kill the process directly;

```sh
netstat -ano | findstr :XXXX
```

XXXX <<<<----put the number of the port you have problem, system show it always, then when you press enter the system show you a message with a real port that one is what you need killing, so put this:

```sh
taskkill /F /PID XXXX
```

XXXX <<<<----the number of the port you want to kill and what system gave you after the first command

Answer (score 0):

type this in command prompt

```
netstat -ano | findstr :XXXX  <-THIS IS THE PORT NUMBER YOU used
```

And it will give you something like this

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080 ||  0.0.0.0:0  || LISTENING | tttt

TCP    [::]:8080  ||  [::]:0  ||  LISTENING || tttt<--thiss is the number you needed
```

then type this in command prompt

```
taskkill /PID tttt /F  <--then enter

result will be something like -->
```

The process with PID `tttt` has been terminated.